# JQuery - keep a div in animated state whilst hovering over a different div?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, bind

I am trying stuff that's out of my depth as usual! I'm trying to make a navigation for my new website, it's supposed to slide down when the user hovers over another div. That other div will have a graphic of some sort saying "menu". I need to nav to stay open when hovering over the "other" div or the menu div itself. So far I have it working but on a div the menu is inside, which is not really the right thing.

Is there some way to bind these two divs together or something like that? Wish I was better at JQuery!

[My site is here if you would like to take a peek](http://www.ransomedesign.co.uk/new_designs/). The white div represents the div the user would hover over to open the menu.

Any help is welcome, thanks :D

Comment: one min im making a fiddle for ya

Comment: +1 for using "whilst" in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/dpBBp/

here is the updated js:

```
$('.menu_button').hover(function() {
    $('#nav').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $('#nav').slideUp();
})
```

See html in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Neal, just taking a look. Love the random cat image!

Comment: @Dan if this the answer you are looking, or if the other one is, remember to select one as `accepted`

Comment: @pixelbobby thnx ^_^ upvotes dont mean much to me anymore today lol. im at the limit. now what i want is some accepted answers :-p

Comment: Don't worry I won't forget. I'm changing the code now. Hosting is playing up a little which isn't helping matters...

Comment: @pixelbobby lol i ddnt see this comment until i posted the comment on the other Q haha

Comment: ok, if you check out the link to the site again you will see your code in action. The only thing that seems a little odd to me is putting the menu which is large, inside the menu div that is smaller. Sure that's a good idea? Haven't seen the site in IE yet haha

Comment: @dan so check it out. its all perfectly fine. there should be no issue ( i did not check IE )

Comment: ok cool. Thank you very much for the speedy responce. This website and the people that use it are fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Container all of the elements within a div and target that div. 
Something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href='#'>Nav Item</a>
        <div style='display:none;'>
            <ul>
                <li>Sub nav 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </li>

</ul>

<script>
$("ul > li").hover(function(){
    //on roll over
}, function(){
    //on roll out
});
</script>
```

On a side note on your site you should use sprites as background images and switch the background position on hover, it will get rid of the jump when you roll over the elements.

Comment: Yep, that's on the to-do list. I need to re-cut my background images side-by-side so there is no load time when hovering. I'm just being slack :P